# When webform block submitted send email to node author and site admin -how?

Tags: webforms, emails, nodes, notifications

This is scenario which I try to reach on my website for free blogging:

1. There is created universal [webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) **Contact author** with fields *name*, *email* and *text* which is as block *(display webform as block checked)* displayed under every blog node type.
2. When reader submit this block, submitted values are send as email to author of blog post *(node author)*, site admin *(me)* and possibly to submitter *(reader)* email.

Is there any possible solution involving webform? What's best combination of modules to do it so, if not webform *(I prefer some webform solution)*?

**Update:** For Webform 4.x I use token `[current-page:node:author:mail]` for "*E-mail to address*" in "*E-mails*" tab. You can find more details [in this tutorial I wrote](http://www.jasom.net/webform-is-submitted-send-email-to-the-current-node-author).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution (IMHO) doesn't actually work: you should be able to use the [Tokens](https://drupal.org/projects/tokens) module and use a proper token to fill a recipient field. For example:
`[node:author:mail]`

However, Webforms only appears to support its own *%something* tokens, and those only relate to the current user and the webform id (not the id of the node being read).

So instead, write the site's inevitable custom module and use [`hook_mail_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to change the To address.

Another resource I read (and have now lost) suggested setting the Webforms recipient to something easily recognizable, like "replace-me@mysite.com".

Then in your `hook_mail_alter()` function,

1. confirm the form's identity,
2. get the current post's author,
3. get that user's email address, and
4. use it in the Recipients. (Along with the admin & the poster, as you like.)

Comment: You can use tokens in webform, can't you? [This thread](http://drupal.org/node/1475926) shows it was added, at the same time removing some tokens people was using. And it seems people succesfully used [my solution to add additional tokens](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69836/how-can-i-store-the-user-agent-string-and-referrer-for-webform-4-x-submissions/73149#73149) in webform. Your answer seems to be in opposition to what I've learned.

Comment: @Molot, Maybe the difference is in the version, something I didn't ask Jasom about at the time. It looks like they added proper, Drupal-style Tokens to the 4.x alpha version. I would have been using the stable 3.x version on a production site. Also, thanks for your link to your solution just for the token-implementation example!

Comment: -- Jasom, if this is still relevant to you, what version of Webform are you using? As Molot points out, if you can use v. 4, you can use Tokens.

Comment: Guys, do you know what is funny? 2 years later Google returned this page for me, I'm reading the question (with "bla bla, too much text, what's the best answer" in my mind) and then I found out that I wrote this question :D :D Right now, I'm using Webform 4.x

Comment: Here's a tutorial how to send email to the current node author http://www.jasom.net/webform-is-submitted-send-email-to-the-current-node-author