# How to track users site use in a webform / contact form?

Tags: webforms, emails

I was wondering if anyone knows a way of adding some data to the end of the emails I receive from a contact / web form, such that I can see what pages users (authenticated and unauthenticated) have visited prior to submitting the form?

Something like:

---

```
Here is the main body of the web form.

Before submitting this form the user visited:
/node/1,
/node/12,
/contact-us,
/node/45,
etc etc...
```

---

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less the feature of the [Google Analytics Contact Form, Webform, Rules Email](http://drupal.org/project/contact_google_analytics) module.

> This module will instantly append Google Analytics information to the bottom of the Contact Form, WebForm, and Rules emails.

The mail would look something like:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: [GA Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) "You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an individual...". So, if Google will ever know someone uses this, it can ban him from using GA. Thus, sending data from this module to **Google** Mail, as shown on the picture, seems particularly bold move to me...

Comment: @Mołot This module has been around for a while now and 2800+ sites are using it. And as per the terms of service. I don't see the information in the mail anyway helping in personally identifying an individual. This data can also be seen at the Analytics. So, IMHO the module isn't violating the terms of service.

Comment: Let me quote a bit more from TOS: "data that personally identifies an individual (**such as a name, email address** or billing information)" emphasis mine. On the picture, name of the user WAS collected, and it is a direct violation of this line in GA TOS. Collecting emails to be able to reply would violate the very same line. Collecting anonymous comments would not.

Comment: @Mołot : I don't understand where the name _is_ being collected. If you are referring to _Term: brian stevenson_, then it is not the name but the term entered in Google search (as you can see the website is of Brian and the search is organic, which leaded the user to the website). So, it is not the name but the terms used in Google search.

Comment: OK, as long as the message sent thorough that form does not carry any way to identify or contact given user, it's not in violation with TOS. Picture was misleading for me, "XX yy sent an email", where xx yy looks like full name, seemed obvious. Consider changing image for a bit less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If your mail-sending-module supports tokens, you could [provide tokens with the data you need](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69836/how-can-i-store-the-user-agent-string-and-referrer-for-webform-4-x-submissions) and then simply use them. But this will not give you full trail, only (at best) referrer, one page back. To track him more thoroughly, you need to use make module track him and record last N visited pages in a FIFO. Again, tokens to put it in content seems easiest way to integrate it with mail sending solution.

Google Analytics is good, if all you need is to identify what pages makes people contact you. It's licence forbids using it to track individual users, so if you need it for error reporting and alike, it's no-go.

And don't forget to respect [Do Not Track](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track), it may be required in your jurisdiction and it's only fair everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recently_read module in drupal 7,

https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read

After that u can create token, check if it is provided by module, if not then create custom token and access that token in Email.

Answer (score -1):

You could definitely do this by creating your own Module, but I Google Analytics is free and is built for tracking this sort of thing.  Check out "Event Tracking" and "Goal Flow" in particular.

Comment: Unless OP needs to identify it per singe user - GA forbids that. Unless I missed some changes in their rules?